# snakeyaml 2.0 java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to a user defined class

Tags: java, snakeyaml

the application worked in snakeyaml 1.23. but after upgrade to snakeyaml 2.0.
we got the exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class mytest.InterimYAMLLoader$InterimTopologyData (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; mytest.InterimYAMLLoader$InterimTopologyData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at mytest.YamlTest.main(YamlTest.java:29)
I tried to change the InterimTopologyData config (and all the private members) into public, still doesn't work.
if I

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create a yaml document object based on InterimTopologyData
        Yaml lYaml = new Yaml(new CustomClassLoaderConstructor(
                                    InterimTopologyData.class.getClassLoader(),
                                    new LoaderOptions()));
        try
        {
             File initialFile = new File("C:\\test\\Configuration.yaml");
             InputStream lInputStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
          
         // Parse the yaml file and load it into the custom object
 line 29           InterimTopologyData lInterimTopologyData = lYaml.load(lInputStream); 
      
         // then I changed the custom class object into a normal Object, it will print string like "{config={topology={spspartition=[{id=1, .."
            Object data = lYaml.load(lInputStream); 
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
public class InterimYAMLLoader
{
    private InterimYAMLLoader()
    {
    }

    @Data
    public static class InterimTopologyData
    {
        public InterimConfig config;
    }

    @Data
    public static class InterimConfig
    {
        private InterimTopology topology;
    }
```

Comment: replace with lYaml.loadAs(inputStream, InterimTopologyData.class) will resolve the issue.